# how to pass a null value to a foreign key field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have 2 tables:

`university`:

```
university_id(p.k) | university_name
```

and `user`:

```
uid | name | university_id(f.k)
```

How to keep `university_id` **NULL** in user table?

I am writting only 1 query, my query is:

```
INSERT INTO user (name, university_id) VALUES ($name, $university_id);
```

Here `$university_id` can be null from front end.

`university` table will be set bydefault by me.

In the front end, student will select the university name, according to that the `university_id` will pass to `user` table, but if student is not selecting any university name then is should pass null value to the `user` table for `university_id` field.

Comment: you can edit database field and allow null value to be insert.

Comment: To say that a field is a [foreign key](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) means it is constrained to match a primary key in the specified table.  So it cannot be Null in that case (as matching makes no sense with Null values).  Perhaps you should back up and explain the purpose of your question.

Comment: @hardmath *..So it cannot be Null in that case (as matching makes no sense with Null values)..* -- that is not always true. Foreign keys can be nullable.

Comment: @JW:  Indeed foreign key fields can be nullable (see [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441988/mysql-foreign-key-to-allow-null)) but the foreign key constraint is not enforced with Null values.

Comment: @hardmath http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38bc8

Comment: @JW: Based on the edit the OP made to the question, and the comment made to your answer, the issue arises because the frontend supplies an empty string rather than a valid university ID for an INSERT.  Possibly the frontend should be modified to provide the required foreign key, and possibly the database scheme should be changed to silently accept this constraint failure.

Comment: @JW: The previous question I linked to above presents a situation in which there is a very clear rationale for the kind of one-to-zero-or-one "business rule" you speak of below.  So far the OP hasn't given us that much of an explanation, e.g. when the university ID on the user record will be supplied, if not at the time INSERT is done.

Comment: `university` table will be set bydefault by me.
in the front end, student will select the university name, according to that the `university_id` will pass to `user` table, but if student is not selecting any university name then is should pass null value to the `user` table for `university_id` field.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just allow column `university_id` of table `user` to allow `NULL` value so you can save *nulls*.

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
   uid INT NOT NULL,
   Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
   university_ID INT NULL,    -- <<== this will allow field to accept NULL
   CONSTRAINT user_fk FOREIGN KEY (university_ID)
       REFERENCES university(university_ID)
)
```

**UPDATE 1**

based on your comment, you should be inserting `NULL` and not `''`.

```
insert into user (name,university_id) values ('harjeet', NULL)
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
$university_id = !empty($university_id) ? "'$university_id'" : "NULL";
insert into user (name,university_id) values ('harjeet', $university_id);
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: i have allowed null value but when i writting this query its showing error:
`insert into user (name,university_id) values ('harjeet','')`

Comment: See my comment on the Question.  A Null value cannot satisfy the foreign key constraint.

Comment: no, an empty string is not the same with null as empty string has value but just empty while null has nothing on it. you should specify it as `NULL` eg, `insert into user (name,university_id) values ('harjeet',NULL)`

Comment: @hardmath *..A Null value cannot satisfy the foreign key constraint...** -- no. that's why we have `one-to-zero-or-one relation`.

Comment: so finally I have to go with modification in UI only :( .

Answer (score 4):

Here suppose i have foreign key `user_id` and i want to insert null value for that.

[image]

Checkbox must be checked for insert null value for foreign key.

Comment: It's unclear what software this is. The answer is also specific to a particular MySQL client software (managing the database), and not generic to the database itself.

Comment: This is phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

I was using MySQL InnoDB and even allowing NULL in the FK column and using NULL as default I was getting an error.
So I used the SET syntax:

```
INSERT INTO (table) SET value1=X...
```

And I just don't set the FK column.